# Contextual closure type '() -> Void' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body error show

Tags: swift

```
   static func animate(_ duration: TimeInterval,
                        animations: (() -> Void)!,
                        delay: TimeInterval = 0,
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [],
                        withComplection completion: (() -> Void)! = {}) {

        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: duration,
            delay: delay,
            options: options,
            animations: {
                animations()
            }, completion: { finished in
                completion()
        })
    }
```

> Using above class in my swift file and create function like below

```
SPAnimation.animate(durationScalingRootView,
                        animations: {
                            rootViewController.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        },
                        delay: delayScalingRootView,
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut,
                        withComplection: {
                            finished in
                            //rootViewController.view.layer.mask = nil
    })
```

Get this error

> Contextual closure type '() -> Void' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was
>   used in closure body

Comment: You should place the arguments on the same line as the opening brace.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
withComplection: {
    finished in
    //rootViewController.view.layer.mask = nil
}
```

If you look at your method declaration, the completion handler is of type `(() -> Void)!`. It does not take any arguments. Your closure above takes one argument - `finished`. As a result, the error occurs.

You remove the `finished` argument from your closure:

```
withComplection: {
    //rootViewController.view.layer.mask = nil
}
```

Or you edit your `animate` method to accept a closure taking one argument:

```
static func animate(_ duration: TimeInterval,
                    animations: (() -> Void)!,
                    delay: TimeInterval = 0,
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [],
                    withComplection completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

    UIView.animate(
        withDuration: duration,
        delay: delay,
        options: options,
        animations: {
            animations()
        }, completion: { finished in
            completion?(finished)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.) You misspelled completion

2.) remove the closure parameter `finished in` in you SPAnimation function

The reason why this doesn't work is that your created function has the closure type simply void. The static function contained in UIView has closure type `((Bool) -> Void)?` therefore you have to put the parameter in there.

Either change the closure type in your animate function in SPAnimate or remove the finished argument in your closure call..

Answer (score 0):

Another example is when you don't use custom argument in a closure and use the $0:

```
someFunctionThatReturnsAClosureWithArgument {
   anotherFunctionThatDon'tReturnAnything {
     // Below code will produce the error
     let foo = $0
   }
}
```

Basically the second function `anotherFunctionThatDon'tReturnAnything` doesn't return anything in its closure but you're using the first function argument `someFunctionThatReturnsAClosureWithArgument`

The solution is to state the actual parameter:

```
someFunctionThatReturnsAClosureWithArgument { argument in
   anotherFunctionThatDon'tReturnAnything {
     // Below code won't produce any errors
     let foo = argument
   }
}
```